# Overriding managed versions in maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this dependency in my pom.xml

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and this warning in the file: `Overriding managed version 2.1.3.RELEASE for thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4`

I wonder is it is better to remove the version number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't override the parent versions of spring dependencies.

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot